# Send data to checkedlistbox

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a query with a list of names that I put into a checkedlistbox.
But I also want to send my table key with it. But at the same time I don't want to show it.

current code:

```
        Dim Querynames = (From rec In db.table
                         Select rec.tableKey, rec.Names).ToList

        For Each item In Querynames 
          'Need to send my table key with each name
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(item.Names)
        Next
```

I will be using this table key to query a search. What I would like to prevent is to make a second Linq.

How do I send "hidden" data(which will be the table key) with my checkedlistbox, so I can reach the key from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the entire objects to the `CheckedListBox`, not only the `Names`.

```
For Each item In Querynames 
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Then you should set the [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb.aspx) property.

```
CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Names"
```

so the `CheckedListBox` will just display the `Names` property.

You probably want to use a regular class instead of an anonymous type, so you can cast the items back to access the `tableKey` property.

---

Consider the following example:

```
Sub Main
    Dim clb = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox()

    Dim f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form()
    f.Controls.Add(clb)

    Dim items = new Item() { new Item() with {.TableKey = "Foo", .Names = "Foobar"},
                             new Item() with {.TableKey = "ABC", .Names = "ABCDEFG"}}

    For Each item in items
        clb.Items.Add(item)
    next

    clb.DisplayMember = "Names"

    f.ShowDialog()

    Dim message = String.Join(" and ", clb.CheckedItems.Cast(Of Item).Select(Function(i) i.TableKey))
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub

Class Item
    Public Property TableKey As String 
    Public Property Names As String 
End Class
```

---

Another way would be to just store your query result in an `Dictionary` and later just look up the `Names` <-> `tableKey` pair.

Comment: Very good answer. And thank you very much for giving me two options. I will learn both ways and will also use both to see how they work. For some reason your answer didnt come up on my screen 30 mins ago when I refreshed the page.